# TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type Symbol which has no callable sqrt method

Tags: python, sympy, sqrt

How I can diff with sympy next code :

```
import sympy as sp
x = sp.symbols('x')
fx = sp.lambdify(x, -x**2-8*x-sp.sqrt(10 * x))
df = sp.diff(fx(x))
```

How I can sqrt or something else with symbol?

```
   AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
AttributeError: 'Symbol' object has no attribute 'sqrt'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [110], in <cell line: 4>()
      2 x = sp.symbols('x')
      3 fx = sp.lambdify(x, -x**2-8*x-sp.sqrt(10 * x))
----> 4 df = sp.diff(fx(x))

File <lambdifygenerated-85>:2, in _lambdifygenerated(x)
      1 def _lambdifygenerated(x):
----> 2     return -sqrt(10)*sqrt(x) - x**2 - 8*x

TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type Symbol which has no callable sqrt method
```

Comment: Can you write the equation please. Must be issues with the brackets.

Comment: Once you `lambdify` an expression, only give it numeric values.  Don't use it in `sympy` functions like `sp.diff`.  `np.sqrt` only works with numeric arrays.  Arrays containing `symbols` will be `object` dtype, and will give problems.  Be extra careful when mixing `sympy` and `scipy/numpy`.  It's best to stick with one or the other - unless you are an expert in both.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the proper way to get the differentiation

```
x = sp.symbols('x')
expr = -x**2-8*x-sp.sqrt(10 * x)
fx = sp.lambdify(x, expr.diff(x))
```

Output:

`-2*x - 8 - sqrt(10)/(2*sqrt(x))`

Answer (score 0):

To illustrate my comment.  Create a function with the code shown in traceback:

```
In [20]: def foo(x):
    ...:     return -np.sqrt(10)*np.sqrt(x) - x**2 - 8*x
    ...:
```

It works fine with a scalar, or numeric array:

```
In [21]: foo(1)
Out[21]: -12.16227766016838

In [22]: foo(np.arange(3))
Out[22]: array([ -0.        , -12.16227766, -24.47213595])
```

But when given a `sympy.symbol`, it raises this error:

```
In [23]: x
Out[23]: x

In [24]: foo(x)
AttributeError: 'Symbol' object has no attribute 'sqrt'
```

`numpy` functions like `np.sqrt` first convert their inputs into arrays:

```
In [1]: np.array(x)
Out[1]: array(x, dtype=object)
```

and then attempt to do `x.sqrt()` which gives rise to the `AttributeError`.